# Remove outer list key in Elixir map to extract inner map

Tags: elixir

{I'm trying to remove an outer key of a map which looks like this:

```
    %{
  orders: [
    %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
    %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
    %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
    %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
    %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
    %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
     ]
     }
```

To get:

```
%{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z",
"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z",
"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z",
"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z",
"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z",
"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
```

I've tried pattern matching and extracting the values and zip them into a list to no avail. It seems a really simple step but I am stuck. Is there a way to slice maps?

**EDIT**

Thank you for your efforts, my problem was solved by enumerating my data into a map directly.

```
 def retrieve_order_data(json) do
    json
    |> Enum.map(fn order ->
          {order["cat"]["order_number"], order["cat"]["order_date"]}
    end)
    |> Enum.into(%{})
  end
```

Comment: The result you expect is not clear. Is it a list of the maps?

Comment: The expected result as posted is a 6-element tuple, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comprehensions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) are great for doing things with enumerables. They're not everyone's favorite and never the only solution, but I quite like them.

```rb
iex> outer = %{
...>   orders: [
...>     %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
...>     %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
...>     %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
...>     %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
...>     %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
...>     %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
...>   ]
...> }
iex> for order <- outer.orders, {id, time} <- order, into: %{}, do: {id, time}
%{
  "000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z",
  "000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z",
  "000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z",
  "000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z",
  "000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z",
  "000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. For instance, you could easily solve it using `Enum.reduce/3`. Like:

```rb
iex> m = %{
...>   orders: [
...>     %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
...>     %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
...>     %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
...>     %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
...>     %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
...>     %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
...>   ]
...> }
%{
  orders: [
    %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
    %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
    %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
    %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
    %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
    %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
  ]
}
iex> Enum.reduce(m.orders, %{}, fn x, acc -> Map.merge(acc, x) end)
%{
  "000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z",
  "000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z",
  "000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z",
  "000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z",
  "000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z",
  "000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"
}
```

If the maps inside orders had more than one `{key, value}`, they would also be added to the resulting map. Beware, however, that if one of the keys appears in more than one map, only the last value will be kept. But this doesn't seem to affect your use case

Answer (score 0):

But you can pattern match on it quite easily:

```
iex> %{orders: inner} = %{
...>   orders: [
...>     %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
...>     %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
...>     %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
...>     %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
...>     %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
...>     %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
...>   ]
...> }
iex> inner
[
  %{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"},
  %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"},
  %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"},
  %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"},
  %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"},
  %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}
]
```

Comment: {orders, inner} = JsonLoader.load_to_database(db, "/home/usr/pathtoproject/orders.json")
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{orders: [%{"000147815" => "2018-08-29T11:37:16Z"}, %{"000147814" => "2018-08-07T06:35:22Z"}, %{"000147813" => "2018-08-03T13:07:07Z"}, %{"000147812" => "2018-07-31T11:41:54Z"}, %{"000147811" => "2018-07-31T11:35:00Z"}, %{"000147810" => "2018-07-24T14:52:40Z"}, %{"000147809" => "2018-07-24T14:30:13Z"}, %{"000147808" => "2018-07-24T14:23:32Z"}, %{"000147807" => "2018-07-24T13:59:45Z"}]}

Comment: {orders: inner} = JsonLoader.load_to_database(db, "/home/usr/pathtoproject/orders.json")
** (SyntaxError) iex:9: syntax error before: orders

Comment: You have forgot `%` before `{`.